secure channel for sending partial private keys!
In certificateless cryptography, the KGC must ensure that the partial private keys are delivered securely to the correct entities.
So my question is how KGC can send these keys secretly?
In the other words, what is the mechanism for this secure communication?
Can someone give me an example of these secure channels?

Usually over established authenticated secure channels like TLS/HTTPS.

Maybe they can establish a mechanism in registration phase.
